# How to convert an Array of Strings to an Array of Objects in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, array

I have an array which has following  String values - ['WATER','ENERGY','PAPER','FOOD SAFETY','FOOD AND BEVERAGE', 'INSTITUIONAL','PEST']

Im trying to convert this into an array of objects with a key and value pair but unable to do so. Here is my code:

```
 handleFavOptions(result){
        console.log('divisions data in handleFavOptions', result);
        this.divisionFilterOptions = [];
        this.tempArray = result.map((key) => (
            {
                label: key, 
                value: result[key]
                
            }
        ));
        console.log('temp array is',this.tempArray);
```

the first console log is showing proper output as below:
[image]

But surpringly in the following code the console shows empty Array

```
 this.tempArray = result.map((key) => (
            {
                label: key, 
                value: result[key]
                
            }
        ));
        console.log('temp array is',this.tempArray); // Shows blank
```

Am I iterating in the wrong way? I need in this form where there is a label and key. And the label and key will both be same.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the keys in your object to be?

Comment: it will be a list of those unique divisions itself. Means label and value will be holding the same values. Key will be unique since the list itself will hold only unique values

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

`result` is an Array, and `key` is an item in the array (e.g. "PAPER"). So doing `result[key]` is going to be undefined.

Since you want the label and value to be the same in your object, you would do the following:

```
this.tempArray = result.map((key) => (
    {
        label: key, 
        value: key
            
    }
));
```

Comment: so do I need to map both label and value to the key itself?, what will the conversion look like inside the iteration?

Comment: @Amax1 yes. Does that answer?